# Problems when using Chapel 1.19 along with GASNet PSM (OmniPath) substrate

Tags: distributed-computing, chapel, gasnet

After Changing to version 1.19, but using Omnipath implementation, I'm randomly receiving the following error: `ERROR calling: gasnet_barrier_try(id, 0)`.

I know that the Omnipath implementation of GASNet is no longer supported  by the current version of Chapel. However, I would like to use some features available only in version `1.19`, and the cluster I use runs over an Omnipath network.

In order to use the `PSM` substrate (OmniPath), I proceed as suggested by Chapel's Gitter community:

`export CHPL_GASNET_ALLOW_BAD_SUBSTRATE=true`

`wget https://gasnet.lbl.gov/download/GASNet-1.32.0.tar.gz`

`tar xzf GASNet-1.32.0.tar.gz`

`rm -rf $CHPL_HOME/third-party/gasnet/gasnet-src`

`mv GASNet-1.32.0 $CHPL_HOME/third-party/gasnet/gasnet-src`

Then, I setup other variables:

`export CHPL_COMM='gasnet'`
`export CHPL_LAUNCHER='gasnetrun_psm'`
`export CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE='psm'`
`export CHPL_GASNET_SEGMENT='everything'`
`export CHPL_TARGET_CPU='native'`
`export GASNET_PSM_SPAWNER='ssh'`
`export HFI_NO_CPUAFFINITY=1`

Next, I build the runtime, etc.

However, when I run experiments, I randomly receive the following error:

`ERROR calling: gasnet_barrier_try(id, 0)
 at: comm-gasnet.c:1020
 error: GASNET_ERR_BARRIER_MISMATCH (Barrier id's mismatched)`

Which finishes the execution of the program.

I cannot find in GASNet documentation the reason for this error. I could only find a bit of information on GASNet's code.

Do you know what's the cause of this problem?

Thank you all.

Comment: This strikes me as though it would probably be better as a support issue on Chapel's GitHub issue tracker (https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues) rather than a SO question.

Comment: Hello, Brad. Thank you, I dind't know about Chapel's Github issue tracker. I'm going to move my question.

Comment: The complete solution to this problem can be found at https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/12990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but for the record the current version of Chapel ([1.28.0](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/blob/release/1.28/CHANGES.md)) now embeds a version of GASNet ([GASNet-EX 2022.3.0](https://gasnet.lbl.gov/dist-ex/ChangeLog) as of this writing) that provides `CHPL_COMM=gasnet CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE=ofi` (aka GASNet [ofi-conduit](https://gasnet.lbl.gov/dist-ex/ofi-conduit/README)) that provides high-quality support for Intel Omni-Path.

In particular, there should no longer be any reason to clobber Chapel's embedded version of GASNet-EX with an ancient/outdated GASNet-1 to get Omni-Path support, as suggested in the original question.

For more details see [Chapel's detailed Omni-Path instructions](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/platforms/omnipath.html).

Comment: Hello Dan, thanks for your reply. Looks like the SUBSTRATE=ofi works since Chapel 1.27. Before, it was required to use a customized script that used an older version of Gasnet.